# How exactly does LTspice resolve circuits

Tags: ltspice

How exactly does LTspice resolve circuits ?

Suppose a simple RC circuit (or more simpler if needed). How LTspice will resolve the circuit ? Why the time step is so important ?

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Are you asking how simulations work? Its a whole theory. Naively, it has the mathematical description of the components telling how the values are changing based on the time, inputs and current state. Time step is important because the simulation needs to calculate how much the values are changed during this time, and it also can't be too small because the simulation will need to perform too many steps.

Comment: LTspice is one of the many "spice" programs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPICE They work with lots and lots of **matrices**, you might want to read: https://www.emcs.org/acstrial/newsletters/summer09/HowSpiceWorks.pdf

Comment: This might help: [SPICE (Simulation Program with Integrated Circuit Emphasis)](https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/1973/22871.html)

Comment: Thank you for the links ! I will take a look on it :) And specially on HowSpiceWorks

Comment: I think the following book is very underrated and not recommended often enough.  The first couple chapters explain underlying mechanics of SPICE that you won't find elsewhere without looking at and analyzing the source code:  https://www.amazon.com/dp/007911525X/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LTspice's circuit simulator function is one of the many "spice" programs, read about SPICE [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPICE).

Circuit simulators and solvers generally work with lots and lots of **matrices**, you might want to read [HowSpiceWorks](https://www.emcs.org/acstrial/newsletters/summer09/HowSpiceWorks.pdf) for a basic introduction.

**Time step** only is relevant if you do a **transient** (time) simulation. The timestep is a parameter used in the transient simulation and relates to how many timepoints the simulator tries to solve.

More timepoints (smaller timestep) generally means higher accuracy but longer simulation times (as more points need to be calculated).

Before that you dive into transient simulations you should first understand **DC** simulations which is used to find the static (DC) voltages and currents in a circuit.